# Remove log debug displaytag

Tags: java

in my application Java I use library displaytag version 1.2. When I execute the application, it's appears:

```
10:50:09.258 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.displaytag.tags.TableTag - [objeto] first iteration=false (row number=82)
10:50:09.258 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.displaytag.tags.TableTag - [objeto] first iteration=false (row number=82)
10:50:09.258 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.displaytag.tags.TableTag - [objeto] first iteration=false (row number=82)
10:50:09.258 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.displaytag.tags.TableTag - [objeto] first iteration=false (row number=82)
10:50:09.258 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.displaytag.tags.TableTag - [objeto] first iteration=false (row number=82)
10:50:09.258 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.displaytag.tags.TableTag - [objeto] first iteration=false (row number=82)
10:50:09.258 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.displaytag.tags.TableTag - [objeto] first iteration=false (row number=82)
```

How remove this because it is not necessary show debug log.

In my application , I have a logging.properties:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = app.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I included file log4j.properties in src/main/resources and changed my pom.xml

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, A1
log4j.category.org.displaytag.tags.TableTag=ERROR, A1
```

pom.xml:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

That's it!!!